# Button loading and control property not getting changed on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-form-validator

So I have a form which I validate before submit using **[jquery-form-validator](http://formvalidator.net/)** plugin! But the problem here is few lines written on `success` is not getting executed when it goes step by step. **However, they work fine if executed in `console` or executed with `debugger`**. Really a wiered behavior!! Any workaround to come over from this?

**JS**

```
$.validate({
    form:'#contact-form',
    onError: function () {
        toastr.error("Please correct the below errors!", "Error");
        return false;
    },
    onSuccess: function () {
        $("#btnContactUs").button('loading'); //Not getting called
        $('.form-contact form').find('input,textarea').attr('readonly', true).addClass('disabled'); //Not getting called
        var formdata = new FormData($('.form-contact form').get(0));
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#contact-form").attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.result)
                {
                    toastr.success(data.message, "Success");
                    $('.form-contact form').get(0).reset();//Check this
                }
                else
                {
                    toastr.error(data.message, "Error");
                }
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                toastr.error(data.message, "Error");
            }
        });
        $("#btnContactUs").button('reset');
        $('.form-contact form').find('input,textarea').attr('readonly', false).removeClass('disabled');
        return false; // Will stop the submission of the form
    }
});
```

On validation success it calls the Controller method through ajax but without executing first 2 lines.

**UPDATE:** Button `#btnContactUs` is a bootstrap button which has `.button` functionality to show loading text.

Comment: afaik `.button` is nothing - use `.text('loading')`

Comment: Also, what is line 2 supposed to do? disable all the form elements?

Comment: can you try with asyn:false in your ajax call

Comment: @Darren Sweeney.. Sorry!! Forgot to mention!! It's a bootstrap button where you have `.button` functionality to show loading text!! and yea line 2 will not `disable` but just adds a read only property to all form elements and just for UI purpose I've some `CSS` defined for that `disabled` class!!

Comment: I think your onSuccess() method's return false is executing before your inner ajax success callback can run. When you put a debugger, the ajax success callback event occurs and your code runs fine.

Comment: will try commenting it and will check once @Waqar

Comment: @Waqar.. You are right buddy!! it was not with `return false` but it came to last line without waiting for ajax to complete!! Thanks for pointing it out!! :)

Comment: @Waqar.. You can add it as answer!! I'll edit your answer then and will add the proper solution to the problem.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onSuccess() method's return false is executing before your inner ajax success callback can run. When you put a debugger, the ajax success callback event occurs and your code runs fine.

We can solve this with **`$.when`** and **`.then`** functionality of jquery as below:

```
$.when(
            $.ajax({
                url: $("#contact-form").attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data.result)
                    {
                        toastr.success(data.message, "Success");
                        $('.form-contact form').get(0).reset();//Check this
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toastr.error(data.message, "Error");
                    }
                },
                error:function(data)
                {
                    toastr.error(data.message, "Error");
                }
            })
        ).then(function(){
            $("#btnContactUs").button('reset');
            $('.form-contact form').find('input,textarea').attr('readonly', false).removeClass('disabled');
        });
```

Comment: Added the answer, now you can provide your solution

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the control that you are trying to access is not available Or you are starting one process before the completion of previous process. In order to run your AJAX regardless of these situations try to add following setTimeout OR SetInterval above the lines which are not getting exectuted.

Syntax:
SetTimeout: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
SetInterval: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Well this might be one of the scenario to overcome the problem! But I think I found answer which is legitimate!! I will post it very soon!! Anyways +1 for your effort.. :)